# Largest subset of { 0, 1, 2, ..., n } that has no 3+ element arithmetic progressions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Out of all the subsets of $\lbrace 0, 1, 2, ..., n \rbrace$ for some given $n$, how do I compute the size of the largest subset that has no [arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) with 3 or more elements?

I suspect this may be a well researched problem but I can't seem to divine the appropriate search terms.

Comment: Small terms are shown in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A003278)

Comment: @Ross, I think that's a little different. That's an infinite sequence with no 3-term AP, constructed greedily. But it may be that for various $n$ you can do better than an initial segment of the greedy sequence.

Comment: A better OEIS reference is http://oeis.org/A003002 --- also, see the discussion at E10 in Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, 3rd ed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  I hadn't noticed.  Thanks.  It may still be useful.  [A003003](http://oeis.org/A003003) has the largest subset without a 4 term progression.

Comment: I'm glad you found the link I posted. If there's no progression with 3 terms, then there's no progression with 3 or more terms.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Oops, I misread the number on yours and thought it was different. And good point :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to  [Szemerédi's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di%27s_theorem). For progressions of length 3, look at a result by Roth. The Wikipedia page suggests that the best known bound is $$O\left(\frac{n (\log\log n)^5}{\log n}\right)$$ I don't think exact values are known except for small values of $n$.

Comment: Sweet, I finally understand enough to ask an unsolved problem ;)