maximum number of elements in "simple subsets"
I saw an interesting question about subset on a paper and I want to share it with you.
Given that $n\in\Bbb N_+$ and $n\ge4$, define a subset $A\subseteq\{1,2,...,n\}$.
A "simple subset" has the property that for all distinct
$x,y,z\in A$, $x,y,z$ are not in an arithmetic progression.
Denote the maximum possible number of elements in $A$, when $A$ is a "simple subset", as $M(n)$.
For example, when $n=4$, $M(4)=3$. Because the largest "simple subsets" will be either $\{1,2,4\}$ or $\{1,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is not a "simple subset" as there are arithmetic progressions.
Questions:

Prove that $M(m+n)\le M(m)+M(n)$ for $m,n\in\Bbb N_+$, hence evaluate $M(8)$.
Prove that $k\ge8$ if for all $k,n\in\Bbb N_+$ and $n\ge k$, we have $M(2n)\le n$


See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251033/largest-subset-of-0-1-2-n-that-has-no-3-element-arithmetic-progress for a discussion of finite sets with no three-term arithmetic progression.
